# Better approach to handling sqlalchemy disconnects

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We've been experimenting with sqlalchemy's disconnect handling, and how it integrates with ORM. We've studied the docs, and the advice seems to be to catch the disconnect exception, issue a `rollback()` and retry the code.

eg:

```
import sqlalchemy as SA

retry = 2
while retry:
    retry -= 1
    try:
        for name in session.query(Names):
            print name
        break
    except SA.exc.DBAPIError as exc:
        if retry and exc.connection_invalidated:
            session.rollback()
        else:
            raise
```

I follow the rationale -- you have to rollback any active transactions and replay them to ensure a consistent ordering of your actions.

BUT -- this means a lot of extra code added to every function that wants to work with data.  Furthermore, in the case of `SELECT`, we're not modifying data and the concept of rollback/re-request is not only unsightly, but a violation of the principle of DRY (don't repeat yourself).

I was wondering if others would mind sharing how they handle disconnects with sqlalchemy.

FYI: we're using sqlalchemy 0.9.8 and Postgres 9.2.9

Comment: Currently we're using [Pessimistic Disconnect Handling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) with *some* success to mitigate `MySQL has gone away`. We're still seeing one case in production though where we can't seem to recover from that situation, and the transaction can't be rolled back and gets stuck. Though this might have something to do with the fact that we're joining two transactions (ZODB and SQL) and aren't using [Two-Phase commits](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#enabling-two-phase-commit) yet.

Comment: With PostgreSQL, we simply haven't had any disconnects crop up yet, so no experience there.

Comment: So -- you've decided to accept the try/catch/retry logic? We have dozens of query functions in our ORM class and we manage several dozens classes.  This really adds up.  BTW -- we hadn't had any trouble with Postgres restarting until recently when the RHEL oom-killer killed a long running postmaster. Suddenly realized we need to recover from this gracefully.

Comment: No, with [pessimistic disconnect handling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) you register a SQLAlchemy event handler that gets run every time a connection is checked out from the pool, and validates the connection by doing a `SELECT 1` on it before it is returned to be used. But, as the docs state, *"At the expense of some extra SQL emitted for each connection checked out from the pool"*.

Comment: I didn't follow that explanation of what constitutes a `checkout` event. Say you have a connection open, and you are querying some data.  In the midst of processing, the `postmaster` process is terminated. How would the `SELECT 1` help? Or are they saying it get's executed before every single query?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but if your only objection is DRY, you could define a `do_transaction(query)` function which handles the while and try/catch, calling `query` inside.

Comment: The standard connection handler we use across our suites includes a connection Pool through a proxy and a decorator `@event.listens_for(Pool, "checkout")`which calls `dbapi_connection.ping()` and uses exception handlers which in turn raise a sqlAlchemy `DisconnectionError`.on a failure. The `DisconnectionError` handler retries a connection to the DB a few times before deciding MySql has really gone away, and will issue a `session.rollback()` if needed to stop the db lock ups with a half finished session.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way I like to approach this is place all my database code in a lambda or closure, and pass that into a helper function that will handle catching the disconnect exception, and retrying.

So with your example:

```
import sqlalchemy as SA

def main():
    def query():
        for name in session.query(Names):
            print name

    run_query(query)

def run_query(f, attempts=2):
    while attempts > 0:
        attempts -= 1
        try:
            return f() # "break" if query was successful and return any results
         except SA.exc.DBAPIError as exc:
            if attempts > 0 and exc.connection_invalidated:
                session.rollback()
            else:
                raise
```

You can make this more fancy by passing a boolean into `run_query` to handle the case where you are only doing a read, and therefore want to retry without rolling back.

This helps you satisfy the DRY principle since all the ugly boiler-plate code for managing retries + rollbacks is placed in one location.

Comment: This is a good solution, but now I'm poring over the SQL Alchemy docs to see if this can be applied to every query automagically rather than having to pass it into run_query.

Comment: I haven't yet found a better solution than monkey patching all the functions on the query object to apply it automatically. I'm still hoping to find a solution through SQL Alchemy event listeners. It looks like the new pool_pre_ping=True might resolve it in newer versions of SQL alchemy.

Comment: A wrapper would be nice instead of a helper function.

Answer (score 1):

Using exponential backoff (https://github.com/litl/backoff):

```
@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError,
    factor=7,
    max_tries=3,
    on_backoff=lambda details: LocalSession.get_main_sql_session().rollback(),
    on_giveup=lambda details: LocalSession.get_main_sql_session().flush(),  # flush the session
    logger=logging
)
def pessimistic_insertion(document_metadata):

    LocalSession.get_main_sql_session().add(document_metadata)
    LocalSession.get_main_sql_session().commit()
```

Assuming that `LocalSession.get_main_sql_session()` returns a singleton.